# Replacing a DLL on a Windows shared folder that is used by a C# .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dll

We have an enterprise management software that our clients deploy to a Windows network shared folder that several users from several terminal servers launch our program from.

What we're trying to achieve is a way to replace a DLL while the program is being used by the users to apply patches to fix bugs. At the moment weirdly enough, we are able to rename the old DLL to replace and apply the new one without any errors regarding the file being used.

This causes us two problems though:

- the new DLL isn't loaded by the application if an instance of the same application is still using the old DLL (I think this is a case of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell#Shared_in-memory_modules)
- Exceptions are thrown left and right by applications that were run before the replacing because they were only loaded partially (lazy loading) and the when its time to go look into the file for the parts that are missing that are being requested the IL code doesn't match what's in memory anymore.

The bottom line of this is I think that we're doing something we are not supposed to: renaming something that is being used.

The possible solutions I found so far are two:

- launch the application with a new AppDomain with shadow copying enabled, but this is not reliable as every client has its own environment and we might get unexpected permission errors or something of this nature
- load assemblies without locking them. On this note we've looked into using reflection (which we actually use to some extent) but we're unsure on how to load through reflection assemblies that are already referenced in the project by the DLL (we have multiple DLL referecing other DLL that are referencing other DLL, etc....).

Do any of you have any other idea on how to overcome this problem safely? Or how to solve the last point I mentioned above with the reflection?

Comment: When using a .NET framework app, _all_ DLLs must be updated synchronously. An application will fail to load with dlls from two different builds (due to the assembly signature). This is a bit relieved for .NET core, but it's still generally not possible to replace a library of a running process.

Comment: Why is the application on a share, and not installed per terminal server?

Comment: We are not requiring the specific version when add references into our solutions so that problem doesn't occur.

Comment: About why our clients don't install one for each terminal server is simply because when updating they don't want to have a system in place to replicate the updated binaries to other terminal servers so they use put a share in place.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a poor man's version of blue/green deployment.

Deploy your application files into two identical folders

```
\\SomeMachine\d$\MyApp\Green
\\SomeMachine\d$\MyApp\Blue
```

Now put a shortcut in the root folder like this:

```
\\SomeMachine\d$\MyApp\MyApp.lnk
```

Start out with the shortcut pointing at the .exe in the Green folder.

Tell your users to always launch the application using the **shortcut only** (rather than navigating into the Green or Blue folders and launching it there).

When it's time to update a DLL, follow this process:

1. Make the modification in the Blue folder
2. Do whatever testing is required in the Blue folder.
3. Once you're sure it works, update the `MyApp.lnk` shortcut to point at Blue.

Users who started their application before your update will continue to hit the Green folder until they exit the application. Anyone who starts the application anew will hit the Blue folder.

The next time you have to update a DLL, reverse the process. Make the modification in the Green folder, then update the shortcut to point at Green.

This way, you are always updating a folder that nobody is using, then making it available via the shortcut. As long as people exit the application every now and then, you should be able to deploy seamlessly.

If you don't want to use a .lnk file (e.g. your clients aren't on Windows), there are other similar ways to do this by either mapping a drive letter or using a symbolic link. But the principle remains the same.

Comment: click once can help with this as well

Comment: This won't work as when our client update its environment with our new software release (we have an agile deployment of new releases which means every week we put out a new version of the software) we only update one folder. We want to touch our client environment and deployment of new binaries process as little as possible and see if we can first solve it "software" side before jumping into system engineering.